# How to create nested ul li and display contents based on data using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

```
<ul style="border:none">
<li>
<a target="" href="">Videos</a>
</li>
<li>
<a target="" href="">Photos</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

output

```
ul link->videos->video url->local url          note -> on click or click
      ->video path->local path
photos->photo url->local url
      ->photo path->local path
```

how to create a nested ul and li in this manner and on click of videos should open two ul video url and video path and on click of video url should open ul call local url how to achieve this

video url and path are been fetch from database so on click on it..it should display the next ul or li...

Comment: Please post what you have tried or the specific problem you are facing.

Comment: i am not able to create a ul and li after the videos and photos

Comment: I can not undestand what you want. "how to create a nested ul and li in this manner and on click of videos should open two ul video url and video path and on click of video url should open ul call local url how to achieve this" is this a tongue twister?

Comment: @ChristopherRamírez  similar to tonque twister... I meant when i click on the ul video it should open two ul links video url and video path and so click on video url again it should open local url and path

Comment: @dude post what you have tried and I'll post my answer to what I think you want

Comment: @Henesnarfel i am just able to display videos and photos in ul... thats it

Comment: @dude does my answer answer your question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking this is what you may be looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/zfEGE/